# Two objects moving in the same direction; when do they meet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I'm awful at physics and need help with a homework problem from my textbook. It reads as follows:

> You are standing at rest at a bus stop. A bus moving at a constant speed of $5.00 \;\mathrm{m/s}$ passes you. When the rear of the bus is $12.0 \;\mathrm{m}$ past you, you realize that it is your bus, so you start to run toward it with a constant acceleration of $0.960 \;\mathrm{m/s^2}$. How far would you have to run before you catch up with the rear of the bus, and how fast must you be running then?

Obviously I have to use 1D kinematic equations for this, but I have no idea how to solve it or let alone where to even begin and I've been racking my brain for hours. So if someone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Draw it! Make a sketch. Remember coordinate system. Then you can clearly see all known values - *starting positions, velocities, accelerations etc.*
2. Pick one of the four motion (kinematic) equations for each - *one for the bus, and one for you*:
   $$x=x_0+v_ot+\frac 12 at^2\\
   v^2=v_0^2+2a(x-x_0)\\
   v=v_0+at\\
   x=x_0+\frac 12(v+v_0)t$$ For example, in this case I would choose the top one for both.
3. Figure out what they have in common - *they will both be at the same place at the same time, when you catch the bus*. So $x_{bus}=x_{you}$ and $t_{bus}=t_{you}$.
4. Now **solve it**!